# Folland's ''Real Analysis'' Exercise 3.17: Missing hypothesis?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

The following exercise is 3.17 in Folland's *Real Analysis, Second Edition:*

''Let $(X, \scr{M}, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $\scr{N}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra of $\scr{M}$, and $\nu = \mu|\scr{N}$.  If $f \in L^1(\mu)$, there exists $g \in L^1(\nu)$ (thus $g$ is $\scr{N}$-measurable) such that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E g d\nu$ for all $E \in \scr{N}$; if $g'$ is another such function then $g = g'$ $\nu$-a.e.  (In probability theory, $g$ is called the *conditional expectation* of $f$ on $\scr{N}$.)''

**My question is this**:  Is Folland missing a hypothesis that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite?  This is not necessarily true even if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.  For example, if $\mu(X) = \infty$ and $\scr{N} = \{X, \emptyset\}$, then $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

The obvious way to go about solving this exercise is to define a measure $\lambda$ on $(X, \scr{N})$ by $\lambda(E) = \int_E f d\mu$.  Then $\lambda <\!\!< \nu$.  So *if $\nu$ is assumed to be $\sigma$-finite*, one may apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem in the form of Exercise 3.14, which I quote here, to obtain the desired result (using Exercise 3.14 eliminates the need to worry about whether $\lambda$ is $\sigma$-finite):

''If $\nu$ is an arbitrary signed measure and $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $(X, \scr{M})$ such that $\nu <\!\!< \mu$, there exists an extended $\mu$-integrable function $f \colon X \to [-\infty, \infty]$ such that $d\nu = f d\mu$.''

Of course, in my proof of Exercise 3.17, I am making the replacements $\nu \to \lambda$, $\mu \to \nu$, and $\scr{M} \to \scr{N}$ in the statement of Exercise 3.14.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't know whether it's called a coincidence or not, the exact same question has strucked to my mind while trying to solve this question but fortunately your post saves my time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a good observation, and I think you are right.

In particular, if as in your example we have $\mu(X) = \infty$ and $\mathcal{N} = \{X, \emptyset\}$, then $L^1(\nu)$ contains only the zero function.  So if $f \in L^1(\mu)$ is any function with $\int_X f\,d\mu \ne 0$ then there will be no $g \in L^1(\nu)$ with $\int_X f \,d\mu = \int_X g \,d\nu$.  Thus without the extra hypothesis the theorem is not true.

Note that in the usual setup of "conditional probability" the measure $\mu$ is actually a probability measure.  In particular it is finite, hence so is $\nu$.

Comment: I found your answer very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @NateEldredge$:$ $L^1(\nu)$ contains only zero function because $\mu (X) = \infty$ and there doesn't exist any $E \in \mathcal N$ such that $0 \lt \mu (E) \lt \infty.$ Am I right? For otherwise if such an $E$ is there in $\mathcal N$ then we could have taken $0 \neq \chi_E \in L^1 (\nu).$

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa: That's correct.