# Radon-Nikodym with a smaller $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure. Let $M' \subset M$ be a smaller $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu' = \mu|_M$.

Show that there exists a unique $g \in L^1(\mu')$ such that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E g d\mu'$ for all $E\in M'$ with $\|g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$.

My attempt:

I want to use Radon-Nikodym theorem here. But I'm not sure how to deal with the $\mu'$, since the version I learned requires both measures to be $\sigma$-finite.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is $f$ ? Do you mean: "Show that for all $f \in L^1(\mu)$, there exists a unique $g \in L^1(\mu')$ such that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E g d\mu'$ for all $E\in M'$ with $\|g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$"?

Comment: Yes, $\mu'$ may **not** be $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I think you want $\mu$ to be finite, in which case this is the definition of the conditional expectation of a random variable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003666/follands-real-analysis-exercise-3-17-missing-hypothesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is:

> Let $(X,M, \mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Let $M' \subset M$ be a smaller $\sigma$-algebra. Let $\mu' = \mu|_{M'}$.
>
> Show that for all $f \in L^1(\mu)$, there exists a unique $g \in L^1(\mu')$ such that $\int_E f d\mu = \int_E g d\mu'$ for all $E\in M'$ with $\|g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$.

This result, as stated, is **false**. Here is a counter-example.

Consider $(X,M, \mu)$ where $X=\Bbb R$, $M$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure. We know that $(X,M, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space.

Now, let $M'=\{\emptyset , \Bbb R\}$. Then $M'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and  $M' \subset M$. Let $\mu' = \mu|_{M'}$.

Let $f$ be any function in $L^1(\mu)$ such that $0< \int_{\Bbb R} f d\mu < +\infty$. Note that $g \in L^1(\mu')$ if and only if $g=0$.

So there is **no** $g \in L^1(\mu')$ such that $\int_{\Bbb R} f d\mu = \int_{\Bbb R} g d\mu'$

**Remark**: The key issue is that, even $\mu$ being $\sigma$-finite, $\mu'$ may not be $\sigma$-finite.

If we add to the question the **additional hypothesis** that $\mu'$ is $\sigma$-finite, then the result holds.

Just define on $M'$, the measure $\nu$ defined by, for all $E \in M'$, $\nu(E)= \int_E f d\mu$. Clearly, $\nu \ll \mu'$ and since now $\mu'$ is $\sigma$-finite, we can apply Radon-Nikodym theorem and conclude that  there exists a unique $g \in L^1(\mu')$ such that, for all $E\in M'$,
$$\int_E f d\mu = \nu(E)= \int_E g d\mu'$$

Then, let $\textrm{sign}(g) = \chi_{[g>0]} - \chi_{[g<0]}$. Since $g$ is $M'$-measurable function, so is $\textrm{sign}(g)$. So we have
\begin{align*} 
\int_X |g| d\mu' & = \int_X  \textrm{sign}(g) g d\mu'=
 \int_X  \textrm{sign}(g)  d\nu =  \int_X  \textrm{sign}(g) f d\mu \leqslant 
\int_X |f| d\mu
\end{align*}
So $\|g\|_1 \leq \|f\|_1$.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose $f$ is a given element of $L^{1}(\mu)$.

Consider $(X,M)$ with the measures $\mu'$ and $v$ wher $\nu (E)=\int_E f d\mu$. $\nu$ is  real (or comlex)  measure and $\nu << \mu'$. Hence. there is a unique $g \in L^{1}(\mu')$ such that $\nu(E)=\int_E gd\mu'$ for al $E \in M'$.

Using a simple function approximation you can see that $\int ghd\mu' =\int fh d\mu$ for any bounded measurable function $h$. Taking $h=\frac {|g|}g$ when $g \neq 0$ and $1$ when $g=0$ we se that $\int |g|d\mu' =\int fhd\mu\leq \int|f|d\mu$ since $|h|=1$